# Caracteres extraños en Wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress, apache

Buenas

Cada vez que inicio el apache,y abro mi pagina wordprees en local ,me sale esto: http://prntscr.com/elfqj8

La foto de arriba sale en toda mi pagina web,da igual que sea el index o contacto o cualquier otra pagina del menu.

Lo raro es que cuando entro al panel de control,y creo una page nueva y la guardo mi pagina web se ve ya bien.
La page que creo no hago nada especial,solo le pongo un titulo y de texto le pongo "prueba" y le doi a publicar.
Al mismo momento que la guardo la elimino y la pagina web se ve bien.

No se si alguien sabra que pasa..

Answer (score 1):

Los carácteres extraños que dices no son tal, son en realidad una imagen (http://image.prntscr.com/image/7af9ca13894e48c4bf911f1e203f52c7.png) que se está cargando en una propiedad [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Elemento/meta) de tu página. Parece ser algo relacionado con Twitter.

Quizá algún plugin ha introducido dicha propiedad la cual **hará aparecer esa imagen en todas las cabeceras de las páginas de tu sitio que utilicen esa plantilla**.

Si no quieres que aparezcan tendrás que modificar la plantilla, cambiar la configuración del posible plugin que las está introduciendo, o la configuración de los scripts y contenido del header (encabezados) si usas frameworks como Thesis o Genesis.

```
<meta name="msApplication-ID" content="microsoft.build.App"/> 
<meta name="msApplication-PackageFamilyName" content="4e8b7b8d-6660-4650-add4-5999bc13c1c3"/> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="es"/> 
<meta name="twitter:card" content="photo"/> 
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Captura de pantalla"/> 
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@light_shot"/> 
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Capturado con Lightshot"/> 
<meta name="twitter:image:src" content="http://image.prntscr.com/image/7af9ca13894e48c4bf911f1e203f52c7.png"/> 
<meta property="og:site_name" content="Lightshot"/> 
<meta property="og:title" content="Captura de pantalla"/> 
<meta property="og:image" content="http://image.prntscr.com/image/7af9ca13894e48c4bf911f1e203f52c7.png"/> 
<meta property="og:description" content="Capturado con Lightshot"/> <meta property="og:url" content="http://prntscr.com/elfqj8"/> 
<meta property="og:type" content="website"/> 
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="154822244543652"/>
```

Comment: Si se desactiva el plugin deberia ir la pagina ya no?Que sentido tiene que creando una page nueva se solucione el problema?Cada vez que inicio el apache y me sale esa pantalla,creo una page la guardo la elimino y funciona todo bien.Coomo supiste el que fallo es del plugin de twitter?

Comment: No entiendo bien eso que dices del Apache. Revisé el código fuente de tu pagina (eso puede hacerlo cualquiera pues está en las opciones de todos los navegadores). WordPress funciona con plantillas o sea son como modelos que tenemos y cada página que creemos eligiendo ese modelo mostrará un contenido fijo determinado. Como eso está en un meta pensé que podría ser una plantilla o un plugin o un script o configuración en el header de tu pagina.